# What's the right interpretation of temperature for the Ising model, and can one think of a theoretical thermometer in that case?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, ising-model

What is the interpretation of temperature in the Ising model? Can one describe a theoretical thermometer for the Ising model?

As far as I know, in the theory of gases, temperature is interpreted as a quantity proportional to the mean kinetic energy. A thermometer is a device capable of converting the average collisions of particles into the movement of a dial. The higher the mean kinetic energy, the more movement the device registers, and the dial goes up. I can't grasp a similar idea for the Ising model.

Comment: Temperature is the internal energy increase per unit entropy, or even better, the reciprocal temperature (coldness) is equal the increase of entropy per unit internal energy, $\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}$, in a fixed mechanical/electrical/magnetic,.. configuration; it is not the average of anything unless you are talking about a very *ideal* gas.